# Which of "self-loathing" and "self-hate" is the stronger feeling?

Tags: word-choice, difference

Which of "self-loathing" and "self-hate" is the stronger feeling?

I have searched the internet and there seems to be different opinions on this. Could I please have yours?

Answer (score 1):

Consider the simpler words, loathe and hate.

Under this definition of "loathe", M-W has a guide for choosing among synonyms of loathe:
[Merriam-Webster "loathe"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/loathe)

> Choose the Right Synonym for loathe
> hate, detest, abhor, abominate, loathe all mean to feel strong aversion or intense dislike for.
> **hate** implies an emotional aversion often coupled with enmity or malice.
> *hated the enemy with a passion*
> detest suggests violent antipathy.
> *detests cowards*
> abhor implies a deep, often shuddering repugnance.
> *a crime abhorred by all*
> abominate suggests strong detestation and often moral condemnation.
> *abominates all forms of violence*
> **loathe** implies utter disgust and intolerance.
> *loathed the mere sight of them*

(M-W text slightly edited for format and readability)

There are differences in quality between the words, apart from just their intensity, or strength. That said, to me, **self-loathing** sounds a bit stronger and more visceral than **self-hatred**.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's impossible to say which is the stronger feeling, because in my opinion they refer to different things:

- Self-loathing is a feeling of intense dislike towards one's own person, personality, habits, and so on.
- Self-**hatred** is often used in the context of group identity. There is the famous trope of the self-hating Jew, for example. It refers to being uncomfortable with characteristics of your group.
- Self-hate is not a term I have often heard, though I'm sure it is used by some. For me, self-hatred sounds more correct.